# How to get the MS Band region setting

Tags: win-universal-app, microsoft-band

I am displaying numbers and currency values on a Band custom tile. How can I get the current region setting of Band so I can format the numbers correctly?

The Band region can be set via MS Health app: Preferences, choose your region (Format for date, time, etc on your Band).

Answer (score 1):

Getting the region setting of the band from the Microsoft Band SDK is not currently supported.

But it seems like you have a good use case, so it is something you might want to add to the Microsoft Band/Health User Voice:

https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot get the exact set region from the Band itself, you may be able to use the "preferred locale" information of the user's [Microsoft Health profile](http://developer.microsoftband.com/cloudAPI/Explorer#!/Profile/Profile_Get), obtained via the [Microsoft Health (Preview) Cloud API](http://developer.microsoftband.com/cloudAPI).